# Datepicker bootstrap 5

Tags: datepicker, bootstrap-5

I have switched from bootstrap4 to bootstrap5 and I'm struggling with the date picker. Please help if someone has worked on this.
I have added the date picker plugins also, but still, it's not working.

The date picker icon is also not working.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
});
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5Oom 
    GNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Datepicker -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap- 
    datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
  <!-- CDN JS -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <!-- Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Atwg2Pkwv9vp0ygtn1JAojH0nYbwNJLPhwyoVbhoPwBhjQPR5VtM2+xf0Uwh9KtT" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- datepicker -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap- 
    datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js" integrity="sha512- 
    GDey37RZAxFkpFeJorEUwNoIbkTwsyC736KNSYucu1WJWFK9qTdzYub8ATxktr6Dwke7nbFai
    oypzbDOQykoRg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
  <title>Date Picker</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class='col-sm-6'>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
            <input type='text' class="form-control" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: "Not working" is never a technical description of a problem. [ask]

Answer (score 57):

The datetimepicker: `https://cdnjs.com/libraries/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37` is for Bootstrap 3, not Bootstrap 5.

Use an HTML5 date input instead...

```
<label for="startDate">Start</label>
<input id="startDate" class="form-control" type="date" />
```

https://codeply.com/p/zU0EWDmIfn

Comment: I can see in your snippet there's some date formatting when setting the values to the span element. How is that done? By the way, it would be great if you just take your code from that site to SO, in case that site goes down.

Comment: @carloswm85 As far as I have seen in Zim's code, there is no format applied to the span element beyond the applied by HTML specs. It is documented in MDN that the format of the input `value` is always ISO8601, for the sake of brevity, it's "yyyy-mm-dd". The appearance of the input may vary between browsers and locales.

Comment: Admittedly, the Nilanj solution is not modern, but it works!

Comment: This solution saves me from 20 lines of codes! man.. it works!

Comment: `type="date"` is buggy at best, in firefox (tried on 109~118 and it doesn't honor device setting (e.g. when device is set to show yyyy-mm-dd it shows mm/dd/yyyy)

Comment: it uses format maybe by browser setting like mm/dd/yyyy while I want Y-m-d

Comment: 3 hours spent searching how to make datepicker work correctly. I should have added "5" to my google search when I typed "bootstrap date field". One weird thing : even didn't see talking about date in Bootstrap 4 doc. The first place I went ... thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think This will work as bootstrap 5 DatePicker.

use below cdn links

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
```

Use below code as date input form

```
<form>
        <div class="row form-group">
            <label for="date" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">Date</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="input-group date" id="datepicker">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    <span class="input-group-append">
                        <span class="input-group-text bg-white d-block">
                            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Use the below function to call date input

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#datepicker').datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also try this implementation of datepicker for Bootstrap 5:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 5 DatePicker</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/gijgo@1.9.14/js/gijgo.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/gijgo@1.9.14/css/gijgo.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <input id="datepicker" width="276" />
    <script>
        $('#datepicker').datepicker({
            uiLibrary: 'bootstrap5'
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/atatanasov/pen/WNyxMoN

Comment: codepen requires http referer (privacy issue) otherwise will not show output. use inline display script like the one [webworm84's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76020965/1041046) is using

Answer (score 3):

One replacement for bootstrap-datepicker is [vanillajs-datepicker](https://github.com/mymth/vanillajs-datepicker). It works with bootstrap 5 and also with other css frameworks.

For [styling with bootstrap 5](https://mymth.github.io/vanillajs-datepicker/#/?id=bootstrap) the correct css must be referenced

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vanillajs-datepicker@1.3.1/dist/css/datepicker-bs5.min.css">
```

and the button class must be set when creating the datepicker

```js
const datepicker = new Datepicker(elem, {
  buttonClass: 'btn',
});
```

I switched from bootstrap 3 and it would have been more work to use the html5 date input as a lot of date ranges were used. Those are also supported, you just have to use the `DateRangePicker` constructor.

Answer (score 1):

I prepared  `datetimepicker` for `bootstrap 5` . I used [datepicker](https://getdatepicker.com/) and [clockpicker](https://weareoutman.github.io/clockpicker/) plugins for this. Also you can translate the calendar content in `.js file` for your language if your own language is not English.

You can control codes on codepen also: https://codepen.io/yusufdogandev/pen/OJBNmPP

```js
$(function () {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker();
});

$(".clockpicker").clockpicker();

$.fn.datepicker.dates["en"] = {
  days: ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"],
  daysShort: ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"],
  daysMin: ["Su", "Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa"],
  months: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
  monthsShort: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
  today: "Today",
  clear: "Clear",
  format: "mm/dd/yyyy",
  titleFormat: "MM yyyy" /* Leverages same syntax as 'format' */,
  weekStart: 0,
};
```

```css
body {
  margin-top: 3em !important;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: white;
}

span i.bi.bi-clock::before {
  font-size: large;
  margin-top: 10px !important;
  margin-left: 5px !important;
}

[placeholder]:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  transition: text-indent 0.5s 0.5s ease;
  text-indent: -100%;
  opacity: 1;
}

input[type="text"],
textarea {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  outline: none;
  padding: 3px 0px 3px 3px;
  margin: 5px 1px 3px 0px;
}

input[type="text"]:focus,
textarea:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(81, 203, 238, 1);
  padding: 3px 0px 3px 3px;
  margin: 5px 1px 3px 0px;
}

input[type="text"] {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(5, 5, 5);
}

input[class="form-control"],
textarea {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  outline: none;
  padding: 3px 0px 3px 3px;
  margin: 5px 1px 3px 0px;
}

input[class="form-control"]:focus,
textarea:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(81, 203, 238, 1);
  padding: 3px 0px 3px 3px;
  margin: 5px 1px 3px 0px;
}

input[class="form-control"] {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(5, 5, 5);
}

span.input-group-text.bg-light.d-block {
  background-color: #fff !important;
  border: none !important;
}
.input-group-append {
  cursor: pointer;
}

i.fa.fa-calendar {
  padding: 4px;
}
.datepicker td,
th {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.datepicker {
  top: 6em !important;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Date-Time Picker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.4/font/bootstrap-icons.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clockpicker/0.0.7/bootstrap-clockpicker.css" integrity="sha512-BB0bszal4NXOgRP9MYCyVA0NNK2k1Rhr+8klY17rj4OhwTmqdPUQibKUDeHesYtXl7Ma2+tqC6c7FzYuHhw94g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clockpicker/0.0.7/bootstrap-clockpicker.min.css" integrity="sha512-MT4B7BDQpIoW1D7HNPZNMhCD2G6CDXia4tjCdgqQLyq2a9uQnLPLgMNbdPY7g6di3hHjAI8NGVqhstenYrzY1Q==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <label for="date" class="col-1 col-form-label">Date</label>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="input-group date" id="datepicker">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date" placeholder="Date Of Birth" />
            <span class="input-group-append">
              <span class="input-group-text bg-light d-block">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
              </span>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <label for="date" class="col-1 col-form-label">Time</label>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="input-group clockpicker" data-placement="bottom" data-align="bottom" data-autoclose="true">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Time Of Birth" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
              <i class="bi bi-clock"></i>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clockpicker/0.0.7/jquery-clockpicker.min.js" integrity="sha512-x0qixPCOQbS3xAQw8BL9qjhAh185N7JSw39hzE/ff71BXg7P1fkynTqcLYMlNmwRDtgdoYgURIvos+NJ6g0rNg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clockpicker/0.0.7/bootstrap-clockpicker.js" integrity="sha512-1QoWYDbO//G0JPa2VnQ3WrXtcgOGGCtdpt5y9riMW4NCCRBKQ4bs/XSKJAUSLIIcHmvUdKCXmQGxh37CQ8rtZQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script src="date-picker.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```