# bootstrap 5 datetimepicker not working properly

Tags: javascript, datetimepicker, bootstrap-5

I am quite new to JS and trying to add datetimepicker to my web-demo. The tutorial works properly with bootstrap 3.3.7, but when I change it to version 5, the calendar is not showing anymore.

Minimal working html is the following

```
<!-- this works OK -->
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"> -->
<!-- this does not! -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/3.1.3/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
  <input type='text' class="form-control"/>
  <span class="input-group-addon\">  
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  </span>
</div>

<script>
  $(".date").datetimepicker({locale: "ru"});
</script>
```

I use `bootstrap@5.1.3` in the project and don't want to change it because of one datetimepicker. I've already tried many variants, but none worked. How can I get it to work?

**UPDATE**

As https://stackoverflow.com/a/68683409/8900030 stated, `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js` is for Bootstrap 3, not Bootstrap 5.

What version should I use instead? (and how do I know that?)

Also note that I need `{locale: "ru"}` parameter, which is not available at bootsrap 3 AFAIR.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Datepicker bootstrap 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68662850/datepicker-bootstrap-5)

Comment: @MWO unfortunately it doesn't, because it is about datepicker but not datetimepicker